# form submit inside div with empty action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, html

Simply my problem is that i want to submit a form in a div with empty action as the php script in the same page,
a simple example to illustrate as my page is too long

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#myDiv").delegate("form", "submit", function(event) {
       $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'), 
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) { 
                $("#myDiv").slideUp(500, function() {
                    $("#myDiv").html(response);
                    $("#myDiv").slideDown(500);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;    
    });
 });
</script>
<head>
<form method="post" action="">
<p> enter your name</p> <input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="save" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
echo $_POST['name'];
}
?>
</html>
```

the problem that the action of the form is empty and so when i click submit button nothing happen, so anyone knows how to solve the problem?
PS: it's too hard to extract the php script in extrnak file, i am searching for alternative solution.

Comment: have you tried to insert the script name inside the action ? e.g. if your file is named `file.php` write on the action `action="file.php"`

Comment: yes i did, nothing happen as well.

Comment: don't write the action="" atrribute

Comment: Have you tried without the jQuery bit? Does the `#myDiv` element exist? Have you tried debugging the jQuery code? Does the handler fire at all?

Comment: yes the div exists, and the script is working as the div slide Up and down when i submit but the name is not echo-ed

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.delegate` to work you have to wrap `#myDiv` around the selector you wish to target, because the targeting is equivalent to:

```
$('#myDiv').find('form').on('submit', ...
```

In other words, your `form` must be wrapped inside `#myDiv`.

Answer (score 1):

tried like this?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
```

This will put the current script address in the action field.

Answer (score 0):

try using a hash symbol. `action="#"`